# Como fazer para aparecer um conteúdo do array em uma DIV pelo <SELECT> do HTML quando seleciono uma certa opção?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control col-6" id="selecionarCategoria">
          <?php  
          $n = 0;
          foreach ($_SESSION['categoria'] as $key => $value): 
            $nomeCanal = $value['categoria'][$key]['category_name'];
            ?>
            <option><?php echo($_SESSION['categoria'][$key]['category_name']);?></option>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
      </div><hr>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 0,10rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/2/22/Logotipo_da_Rede_Globo.png" alt="Globo HD">
          <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center;">
            <h5 style="font color: black; font-size: 18px;">Globo HD</h5>
            <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 10px;">Exibindo agora:</p>
            <p class="card-text">Jornal da Globo</p>
            <a href="live_assistir" class="btn btn-primary">Assistir</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Uma sugestão, você pode fazer um loop colocando o conteúdo do array em uma div e deixando todas escondida, quando ele selecionar uma opção do select, você pode com javascript mostrar a div que corresponde com o a opção do select.

Comment: Muito bom David Vinicius. Eu consegui fazer rodar, gostaria de saber como faço pra quando alguem acessar a pagina, automaticamente a div carregar com a opção do select ja selecionada. Sem ele precisar clicar em algum elemento dentro do select para poder aparecer a div. Gostaria de fazer tipo um autoclick automático no primeiro elemento listado dentro do select.

Comment: você pode usar a função onload no body da página chamando a mesma função que você utiliza para mostrar a div e juntamente colocar o atributo selected no option do select que você quer que apareça.